# How to lay cement board over a small area

Tags: tiling, cement-board

Hi I need to tile a small area 0.85m x 0.9m. I have laid 18mm ply over the original floor board. I now need to add cement board over it to tile.

Which is the best option for laying down the cement board and does it matter:

1. 2 pieces 0.85m x 0.45m
2. 1 piece 0.85 x 0.45 m and smaller pieces to fill the other half (see drawing below)
3. multiple smaller pieces across the entire area
4. Any of the above is fine

[image: Drawing]

Comment: Given that stock size cementboard is 0.914x1.524 meters, one unbroken piece to fit your space should be obtainable from a single sheet.

Comment: @Ecnerwal, great catch.  on the sizing. I was thinking the cement board was 30 x60 inches not 36.

Comment: Could be it's different where the question comes from, but in many cases stuff seems to be the same sizes worldwide even if the units come out whacky for the majority of the world.

Comment: I can't put it in one piece due to the shape of the space without removing the door completely (it is an entrance "lobby"). It has pipes and recesses. It needs to go in 2 pieces minimum.

Comment: You didn't put that information in your question...

Comment: Apologies. Which of the options above is best.

Comment: For you or for the life of the tile? That's two pieces, or taking the door off, respectively. If it's a pipe you're unwilling or unable to disconnect, then there is no other option unless you're 100yo and know how to do a dry pack.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 pieces o.85 x0.45 would be my preference.

However this is a very small area. If 18mm subfloor is one piece it is most likely stable enough to tile right over it, if the extra height of the cement board is not needed.

Edit: this can be done with 1 piece of cement board per Ecnerwal's info.

Comment: Yes the ply is in one piece with sizeable gaps around 10 mm on each side. So I need the cement board to have a smaller gap around. I counted 3 mm.

Comment: 10 mm is not a big gap around the perimeter of the room.  Floor tile is hard enough to overlap that with no ill effects.  and if you are using a base or skirt board it would be covered.

Comment: The tiles are small victorian tiles. The border is made of 25 mm width tiles.